# How to use jQuery's .hover() with a stack of divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a bunch of divs inside a div that are all on top of each other. One of the divs, `.play`, is hidden. When the user hovers over the divs, I want the hidden div to appear.

**HTML**

```
<div class="preview">
       <a href="blackJack.html">
        <div class="gamePreview" id="blackJack"></div>
        <div class="gameName"></div>
        <div class="play">
            <img src="playbutton.png" />
        </div>
        <h3>Blackjack</h3>
        </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.preview {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    position: relative;
}

.gamePreview {
    height: 280px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border: 1px solid darkslategrey;
}

.gameName {
    background-color: #494949;
    height: 150px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.play {
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    opacity: .5;
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 87.5%;
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.play img {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding-top: 110px;
    padding-left: 160px;
}


.preview h3 {
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    opacity: .8;
    padding-left: 5%;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".play").hover(function(){
                $(".play").css("visibility", "visible");
            });
        });
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qj44o9dn/

What I want it to look like on hover: https://jsfiddle.net/qj44o9dn/

Comment: I think the two JS Fiddle links are the same... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build on what Sotiris wrote; You can add an handlerOut to hide the div when the cursor leaves the area:

https://jsfiddle.net/s9ogz1ss/1/

```
$(".play").hover(function () {
    $(".play").css("opacity", "0.5");
}, function () {
    $(".play").css("opacity", "0");
});
```

If you don't want the mouseleave function in this case, you might want to look at the mouseenter function instead:

https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Answer (score 2):

You can't hover something which is invisible as first notice. Secondly you have to include jQuery in your jsfiddle demo.

About your question an alternative could be to remove the `visibility:hidden` and play with `opacity` having it initially `0`.

Then on hover you can change it to what you like.

https://jsfiddle.net/s9ogz1ss/